# How do I start spark shell or submit a spark job from a machine that is not part of the cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have a cluster of 4 DSE 4.6 nodes with Cassandra/Spark in standalone mode, submitting a job to spark or opening a spark shell from one of the cluster nodes works fine.
What I want to do now is to be able to open a spark shell from a machine that is not part of the cluster, so I installed DSE on a new machine but when I try to run

```
$ SPARK_MASTER=spark://MASTER_NODE dse spark
```

I get a bunch of connection errors that look like the spark shell is trying to connect to localhost.

Is there an inherent limitation in Spark that limits running the shell or submitting the jobs only from a node that is a member of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Spark are you on?

Try changing SPARK_MASTER to just MASTER

I usually run

```
MASTER=spark://servername:7077 ./bin/spark-shell
```

And everything connects fine.

Comment: I'm using DSE 4.6, just tried setting `MASTER`, same error: `java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost`

Comment: Can you connect to the host on any other service. The error would suggest that something is stopping you from connecting to the service (Port isn't open to your ip etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found my issue (two actually):

1. I had a different JDK installed on the "client" machine
2. the correct way of specifying a master is `dse spark --master spark://MASTER_ADDRESS:7077`

Now everything works fine.